# How to go about scheduling a task in windows 7 to change wireless connection

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

This may or not be something that can be done. I cannot find anything on the wireless connection manager built into windows 7 let alone methods for passing params into it. Problem is as follows: I have 2 wireless routers. One provides internet access, the other provides sole access to the local network. Every day at 4am the main system creates a backup in 2 locations. One is a External usb drive, the other is a location on the network. This is all cool if it is remembered to change over to the local network router before leaving. But if it is forgotten the roof will collapse, the walls will burn, and I will be... well you get the idea.

Solution: there is already a custom event that fires a automated backup program at 4am everyday. I need someway to force the wireless network to use the correct connection at say 3:58am everyday.

Any ideas????

Answer (score 1):

You probably could use `netsh` and it's  `wlan` capabilities.  You can control almost every aspect of WiFi connectivity with it (connecting/disconnecting included). `Netsh` is scriptable so easy to run as scheduled task. Full description of `netsh wlan` here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx